# What is the rationale for requiring payment "in cash in euros" when applying for a UK visa at the Pyongyang embassy?

Tags: uk, money, embassies, north-korea

The UK government has a [specific page on applying for a UK visa from North Korea](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/democratic-peoples-republic-of-korea-apply-for-a-uk-visa/how-to-apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-democratic-peoples-republic-of-korea) on which they state the following:

> the correct visa application fee, in cash in euros
>
> [...]
>
> You must pay the visa application fee in cash in euros at the British Embassy in Pyongyang. You should ensure that you get a receipt. We cannot accept payment by any other method.

Is there any rationale on requiring the payment be made in euro (rather than, let's say pound sterling or United States dollar)?

This seems weird because the UK does not use the euro (instead it uses pound sterling) and North Korea doesn't officially either. I know some communist countries use foreign currency on a regular basis, however, the [Wikipedia article on the North Korean won](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korean_won#Other_currency_used) mentions the euro isn't used as much because Chinese and American currency is more common.

Comment: The British embassy shares a building with the [German, French and Swedish embassies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embassy_of_the_United_Kingdom,_Pyongyang). Perhaps they use Euros so that they can share cash handling logistics?

Comment: @MJeffryes that's an interesting find, an answer could be based on seeing if the Swedish embassy requires euro or if it accepts Swedish krona (as well). I don't think it's necessarily POB, it's quite likely there is information about it out there somewhere (perhaps even in UK parliamentary records?).

Answer (score 1):

Generally the Euro (EUR), the US Dollar (USD), and the Chinese Reminbi (RMB) are the most widely used foreign currencies in North Korea. In Britain the currency is the British Pound (GBP) but the Euro is easy to exchange here. As it is the British Embassy you probably will find they have chosen the Euro as it is also easily exchangeable in the UK.